# how to make wp_editor startup in visual mode

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I try to make a nice textearea with markup. My users are wel above 40 so they need a wysiwyg editor to load right away.

i use wordpres to and load the field like this:

```
<form style="clear:both" method='post' action="./?id=<?= $_GET['id'] ?>">
<?php wp_editor(getUserData('message'), 'message'); ?>
<div id="message" ></div >
<input type="submit" name='action' value="opslaan">
</form>
```

But that loads the editor of wordpres in html modus. They wil absolutly not get that they need to push visual to get the nice editor. So does anyone know how to make it load in visual mode by default?

thanks

Comment: can you show us the full tinymce configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://trepmal.com/filter_hook/wp_default_editor/) worked for me (Wordpress 3.5.2):

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', 'force_default_editor' );
function force_default_editor() {
    //allowed: tinymce, html, test
    return 'tinymce';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function('', 'return "tinymce";') );
```

right in your page if you don't want to change the default behavior of all your website